# jquery take $(id).html.parent("div") differently

Tags: jquery

not sure how to ask this, so I will give you an example.

```
<div id='page'>
   <div id='take1'> <img> </div>
   <div id='take2'> <img> </div>
</div>
```

If I use jquery and `$("#take1").html()` it takes only `<img>` content.

How should I take `<img>` with its div? I cant use `parent()` in this situation.

```
<div id='take1'> <img> </div>
```

Comment: an id is `#idname` a class is `.classname` you need to know how to reference them when calling them as selectors => `$("#page")`

Comment: i knew that, question was not about that.

Comment: well, make sure your code is correct then, it wasn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dom property [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

```
$("#take1").get(0).outerHTML//$("#take1")[0].outerHTML
```

or

```
document.getElementById('take1').outerHTML
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fEt5U/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write your own outerHTML plugin, take a look here -  http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
  return (s)
  ? this.before(s).remove()
  : jQuery("&lt;p&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

and then use it like:

```
$('#myTag').outerHTML();
```